# is there any difference between runOnUiThread and CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main) in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-runonuithread

I don't know is there any difference between **CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch** and **runOnUiThread**, I think both will run on Main thread.

but still confusion is any difference there.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you can call `runOnUiThread` only in the context of `Activity`.

Secondly, you cannot call suspend functions from `runOnUiThread`, while you can do it in `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch` block.

Thirdly, `runOnUiThread` checks if the current ui thread is busy with other operations, if it is, the task is posted to an activity handler and will be executed when its turn will come.

Comment: does doing this `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch` leak context?

Comment: @Hades if you mean Android context, it most likely doesn't, since it does not use/hold references to context. It just dispatches the job to the same thread in which UI is drawn

Answer (score 1):

They're different things using different technologies, and really it comes down to whether you're already using a coroutine or not. If so, just switch to the *Main* dispatcher when your code needs to be on the main thread. If you're not using coroutines, and you're explicitly using another thread, then you can use `runOnUiThread` to run some code on the main one. If you're not using coroutines *or* threads, then you don't need to call `runOnUiThread` at all!

There's nothing *stopping* you from using `runOnUiThread` from inside a coroutine - but it's not really the right tool for the job, you're stepping outside of coroutine handling unnecessarily. Plus like *Steyrix* says, you need access to something like an `Activity` to do it, which could mean holding a reference to one in a long-running coroutine when it should be garbage collected.

There are lots of other ways to get back on the main thread too, e.g. `post`ing `Runnable`s to a `Handler` (or through a `View`), or the `postValue` methods on `LiveData`. You don't *have* to switch dispatcher if there's something more concise and convenient available, it all depends on the situation